# Is an SSL_CTX object freed when BIO_free_all() gets called?

Tags: c, openssl, free

Many of the client/server examples show the use of an `SSL_CTX` to initialize the SSL side of things, but do not show the `ctx` variable being freed. Reading the documentation, it is not clear whether the context is part of the chain or not, I would say not because it is not a BIO object, but I am not too sure what to think.

The following is the code example from the `man BIO_new_ssl` output. As we can see, they allocate a context at the start with:

```
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());
```

But I do not see any `SSL_CTX_free(ctx)` anywhere. However, it context is attached to `sbio`, which is attached to `bbio` and `acpt` too (Yeah, it is a big mess and they reuse the same variable for varying things!) At some point they call `BIO_free_all(acpt)`. Would that call free the `ctx` variable pointer too? Or that just an omission in the example? (i.e. if I do call the free, will I eventually get a double `free()` error?)

```
    BIO *sbio, *bbio, *acpt, *out;
    int len;
    char tmpbuf[1024];
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL *ssl;

    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    ERR_load_SSL_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    /* Might seed PRNG here */

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());

    if (!SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx,"server.pem",SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)
           || !SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx,"server.pem",SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)
           || !SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx)) {

           fprintf(stderr, "Error setting up SSL_CTX\n");
           ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
           return 0;
    }

    /* Might do other things here like setting verify locations and
     * DH and/or RSA temporary key callbacks
     */

    /* New SSL BIO setup as server */
    sbio=BIO_new_ssl(ctx,0);

    BIO_get_ssl(sbio, &ssl);

    if(!ssl) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't locate SSL pointer\n");
      /* whatever ... */
    }

    /* Don't want any retries */
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

    /* Create the buffering BIO */

    bbio = BIO_new(BIO_f_buffer());

    /* Add to chain */
    sbio = BIO_push(bbio, sbio);

    acpt=BIO_new_accept("4433");

    /* By doing this when a new connection is established
     * we automatically have sbio inserted into it. The
     * BIO chain is now 'swallowed' by the accept BIO and
     * will be freed when the accept BIO is freed.
     */

    BIO_set_accept_bios(acpt,sbio);

    out = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);

    /* Setup accept BIO */
    if(BIO_do_accept(acpt) <= 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Error setting up accept BIO\n");
           ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
           return 0;
    }

    /* Now wait for incoming connection */
    if(BIO_do_accept(acpt) <= 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Error in connection\n");
           ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
           return 0;
    }

    /* We only want one connection so remove and free
     * accept BIO
     */

    sbio = BIO_pop(acpt);

    BIO_free_all(acpt);

    if(BIO_do_handshake(sbio) <= 0) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Error in SSL handshake\n");
           ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
           return 0;
    }

    BIO_puts(sbio, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n");
    BIO_puts(sbio, "\r\nConnection Established\r\nRequest headers:\r\n");
    BIO_puts(sbio, "--------------------------------------------------\r\n");

    for(;;) {
           len = BIO_gets(sbio, tmpbuf, 1024);
           if(len <= 0) break;
           BIO_write(sbio, tmpbuf, len);
           BIO_write(out, tmpbuf, len);
           /* Look for blank line signifying end of headers*/
           if((tmpbuf[0] == '\r') || (tmpbuf[0] == '\n')) break;
    }

    BIO_puts(sbio, "--------------------------------------------------\r\n");
    BIO_puts(sbio, "\r\n");

    /* Since there is a buffering BIO present we had better flush it */
    BIO_flush(sbio);

    BIO_free_all(sbio);
```

Comment: Also see [SSL/TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki and [Does correct freeing of X509 structures differ between chain and main certificate adding?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24263913). The BIO's are usually free'd separately.

Comment: @jww, ah, in the sample on that SSL/TLS Client page they do free the context!